# why if we use "tf.make_template()" in training stage, we must use tf.make_template() again in testing stage

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I defined a model function which named "drrn_model". While I was training my model, I use model by:

```
shared_model = tf.make_template('shared_model', drrn_model)
train_output = shared_model(train_input, is_training=True)
```

It begin training step by step, and I can restore .ckpt file to the model when I want to continue to train the model from an old point.

But there is a problem when I test my trained model.
I use the code below directly without using tf.make_template:

```
train_output = drrn_model(train_input, is_training=False)
```

Then the terminal gave me a lots of NotFoundError like "`Key LastLayer/Variable_2 not found in checkpoint`". 
But when I use

```
shared_model = tf.make_template('shared_model', drrn_model)
output_tensor = shared_model(input_tensor,is_training=False)
```

It can test normally.

So why we must use `tf.make_template()` again in testing stage. What is the difference between `drrn_model` and `make_template` when we construct our model.

**And there is another question: the BN layer in tensorflow.** 
I have tried many ways but the outputs is always **wrong**(always worse then the version without BN layer).
There is my newest version of model with BN layer:

```
tensor = None

def drrn_model(input_tensor, is_training):
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        with tf.variable_scope("FirstLayer"):
            conv_0_w = tf.get_variable("conv_w", [3, 3, 1, 128], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=np.sqrt(2.0 / 9)))
            tensor = tf.nn.conv2d(tf.nn.relu(batchnorm(input_tensor, is_training= is_training)), conv_0_w, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding="SAME")
            first_layer = tensor
        ### recursion ###
        with tf.variable_scope("recycle", reuse=False):
            tensor = drrnblock(first_layer, tensor, is_training)
        for i in range(1,10):
            with tf.variable_scope("recycle", reuse=True):
                tensor = drrnblock(first_layer, tensor, is_training)
        ### end layer ###
        with tf.variable_scope("LastLayer"):
            conv_end_w = tf.get_variable("conv_w", [3, 3, 128, 1], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=np.sqrt(2.0 / 9)))
            conv_end_layer = tf.nn.conv2d(tf.nn.relu(batchnorm(tensor, is_training= is_training)), conv_end_w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

        tensor = tf.add(input_tensor,conv_end_layer)

        return tensor


def drrnblock(first_layer, input_layer, is_training):

    conv1_w = tf.get_variable("conv1__w", [3, 3, 128, 128], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=np.sqrt(2.0 / 9)))
    conv1_layer = tf.nn.conv2d(tf.nn.relu(batchnorm(input_layer, is_training= is_training)), conv1_w, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding= "SAME")

    conv2_w = tf.get_variable("conv2__w", [3, 3, 128, 128], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=np.sqrt(2.0 / 9)))
    conv2_layer = tf.nn.conv2d(tf.nn.relu(batchnorm(conv1_layer, is_training=is_training)), conv2_w, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME")

    tensor = tf.add(first_layer, conv2_layer)

    return tensor

def batchnorm(inputs, is_training, decay = 0.999):# there is my BN layer
    scale = tf.Variable(tf.ones([inputs.get_shape()[-1]]))
    beta = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([inputs.get_shape()[-1]]))
    pop_mean = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([inputs.get_shape()[-1]]), trainable=False)
    pop_var = tf.Variable(tf.ones([inputs.get_shape()[-1]]), trainable=False)
    if is_training:
        batch_mean, batch_var = tf.nn.moments(inputs,[0,1,2])
        print("batch_mean.shape: ", batch_mean.shape)
        train_mean = tf.assign(pop_mean, pop_mean*decay+batch_mean*(1-decay))
        train_var = tf.assign(pop_var, pop_var*decay+batch_var*(1-decay))

        with tf.control_dependencies([train_mean, train_var]):
            return tf.nn.batch_normalization(inputs,batch_mean,batch_var,beta,scale,variance_epsilon=1e-3)
    else:
        return tf.nn.batch_normalization(inputs,pop_mean,pop_var,beta,scale,variance_epsilon=1e-3)
```

Please tell me where is wrong in my code.
Thanks a lot!!